# Basic and fundamental papers in Adversarial Attacks with code

Tags: python, deep-learning, adversarial-ml

I'm looking for basic and fundamental academic papers in Adversarial Attacks or defense. The attack or defense algorithm should be be easy to understand and the code can be found in Python. Where can I find such papers?

Comment: The first part of your question is easy: most recent academic papers are [available online](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=adversarial+attacks&btnG=). But imho you have very high expectations in the 2nd part of the question: academic papers are not always easy to understand and they don't always provide an implementation. It's not my domain so maybe somebody can give an answer which satisfies you, but I wouldn't hold my breath.

Answer (score 0):

I can recommend this [free course on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5wOWcWepktM&list=PLyaM1v1V1Ed_zDss3_kXlHEULSNmS0_Uz). It should be relatively easy to follow and understand. In the lectures, there are references to relevant publications on the topic and slides that explain them in summary. The last video is a laboratory with code examples, but I recommend watching the lectures first. Here is also the link to the GitHub repository of the course, that is constantly updated https://github.com/unica-mlsec/mlsec.

Hope it helps!